# Print Z pattern from 2D String array

Tags: java, complexity

I am trying to print the Z pattern, but the time complexity is coming to \$O(n^2)\$. Is there any way to reduce the time complexity?

```
package matrix;

public class ZPattern 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String a[][] = { {"1","2","3","4","5"},
                {"a","b","c","d","e"},
                {"6","7","8","9", "f"},
                {"g","h","i","j","k"},
                {"m","n","o","p","q"}
            };
        for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<a.length;j++)
            {
                if(i==0||i==a.length-1)
                {
                    System.out.print(a[i][j]);
                }
                else if(i+j==a.length-1)
                {
                    System.out.print(a[i][j-1]);
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `for(int j=0;j<a.length;j++)` looks wrong. Shouldn't that be `for(int j=0;j<a[i].length;j++)`?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Because printing a Z only makes sense for square grids? So in this specific case it doesn't matter much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Bug?

The output from your version:

```
12345
   c 
  7  
 g   
mnopq
```

But the output should be

```
12345
   d
  8
 h
mnopq
```

It's unclear why you chose this.

> ```
>                     System.out.print(a[i][j-1]);
> ```

This could be

```
                    System.out.print(a[i][j]);
```

Then it prints the output correctly.

#### Avoid unnecessary comparisons in loops

You iterate over each element in the entire square and print different things based on an `if`/`else` structure.  But you don't actually have to do that.  Consider

```
    public static void drawZ(String[][] matrix) {
        System.out.println(String.join("", matrix[0]));

        int n = matrix.length - 1;
        for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
        {
            int m = matrix.length - i - 1;
            for (int j = m; j > 0; j--)
            {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }

            System.out.println(matrix[i][m]);
        }

        System.out.println(String.join("", matrix[n]));
    }
```

This is in a separate method, which makes it easy to reuse.

This prints the first and last line separately.  So we don't need that part of the `if`.

This prints the spaces separately from the line of the Z.  So we don't need those parts of the `if` either.

Rather than calculating `i + j - a.length - 1` on every iteration, this code just counts down from `m`, which it calculates once per row.

This calls a Java 8 built-in method to join the characters in a row rather than rolling our own `for` loop.

This prints the equivalent part of the matrix.  If that's not what you want, you can replace `[m]` with `[m - 1]`.  That would give the original behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to print an `N x N` matrix so the inherit complexity is O(n²). No way to go around this.

What you can reduce is the "spaces" you print. More specifically the `O`s in this pattern:

```
ZZZZZ
___ZO
__ZOO
_ZOOO
ZZZZZ
```

Even if you don't print those, the Z pattern stays the same. This then results in code like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] grid = new int[][]{{1,1,1,1,1},{0,0,0,1,0},{0,0,1,0,0},{0,1,0,0,0},{1,1,1,1,1}};
    for(int i = 0; i < grid[0].length; i++){
        System.out.print(grid[0][i]);
    }
    System.out.println();
    for(int i = 1; i < grid.length - 1; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < grid.length-i; j++){
            if(j==grid.length-i-1){
                System.out.print(grid[i][j]);
            } else {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < grid[grid.length-1].length; i++){
        System.out.print(grid[grid.length-1][i]);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

But I really don't think it's worth it. Don't forget that you're just printing a big Z pattern here. Do those couple of milliseconds actually make a difference? I couldn't tell the difference between your near instant printing code and mine after the change ...

So go for readability first, minor optimisations second.
If this was a method that would be executed millions of times it would be a different story.